# Stacked Col Chart with Line graph using sec.axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tibble

I am trying to plot a line graph with a bar chart together with dual axis. I tried to do it but my line chart does not seems to appear, anyone could advise this? Another question, for the inverse bar (negative) is there a way to show positive values instead of negative? Means the bottom should also show a positive count of tweets instead of negative (I created a negative value to inverse the bar).

dput

```
structure(list(Year = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022), Month = structure(c(9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), levels = c("Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
"Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Sentiment = c("Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive"), count = c(-35L, 86L, -86L, 80L, -55L, 65L, -80L, 
241L, -17L, 262L, -65L, 194L, -110L, 223L, -241L, 186L, -72L, 
166L, -262L, 117L), Compound_score = c(0.366274285714286, 0.512205813953488, 
0.4213, 0.5130075, 0.416335294117647, 0.582609230769231, 0.360905454545455, 
0.583192946058091, 0.346581944444444, 0.567261832061069, 0.3731, 
0.567573195876289, 0.400187272727273, 0.564790134529148, 0.280109803921569, 
0.558009677419355, 0.359274, 0.585918072289157, 0.372865625, 
0.565974358974359)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    Year = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022), Month = structure(c(9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", 
    "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 
        11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 19:20), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .drop = TRUE))
```

```
p <- ggplot(df_graph, aes(Month)) +
  geom_col(aes(y=count, color = Sentiment)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Compound_score,group = Sentiment, color = Sentiment)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    
    # Features of the first axis
    name = "Compound Score", limits = c(-500,500),
    
    # Add a second axis and specify its features
    sec.axis = sec_axis(trans=~./500, name="Count of Tweets")
  )

p
```

[image: current plot]

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(df_graph, aes(Month)) +
  geom_col(aes(y=count * ifelse(Sentiment == "Positive", 1, -1), fill = Sentiment),
           position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Compound_score*500,group = Sentiment, color = Sentiment)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    
    # Features of the first axis
    name = "Compound Score", limits = c(0,500),
    
    # Add a second axis and specify its features
    sec.axis = sec_axis(trans=~./500, name="Count of Tweets")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: is there a possibility that the negative and positive could be inverse? like the one i show above.

Comment: I don't know if I understand. You want both bars into negative territory? Then swap `Positive` for `Negative` in the ifelse. I have used it to convert your negative numbers to positive, but if you want both negative than convert the positive numbers to negative.